# How to abbreviate GIS Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion

I understand that the *se* in gis.se is short for *Stack Exchange*. However, on my first days on the site I thought everybody was referring to a Swedish GIS site until I visited the  [Gagnefs industrisnickerier AB](http://www.gis.se/) site.

This is probably a meta meta, but why do some users choose to abbreviate the name of the site as gis.se? It may be confusing for us slower folk that are not good with abbreviations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for the confusion. Personally, I had forgotten .se was a valid top level domain. It's pure laziness, or more nicely said: pure efficiency. gis.StackExchange.com is a lot of characters to type repeatedly and we don't really have anything shorter or sensical to replace it with (yet).

I suppose GIS.stack would be better in the sense it can't be confused with a domain, probably just as confusing for newcomers though.

Comment: Or even just gis-se or something that doesn't look like a domain.

Comment: I like GIS-X?..

Answer (score 2):

Reminds me of the problem with the [Swedish subtitles](http://www.smouse.force9.co.uk/monty.htm) Monty Python had with the Holy Grail.

> We apologise for the fault in the
>   subtitles.  Those responsible have
>   been sacked.

Comment: ahh good old Monty Python

Answer (score 2):

This old Q&A just came up in the sidebar.

For a few years now I have been seeing almost everyone, including myself, using `GIS SE` as the abbreviation for GIS Stack Exchange.

If there are any other abbreviations floating around that anyone uses, and prefers, perhaps they can add them to this question as separate answers for people to upvote/downvote to see what floats to the top.

It looks like no one touched the "how to abbreviate" part of [How are Stack Exchange sites officially branded?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9024/how-are-stack-exchange-sites-officially-branded) at Meta SE.